# Ajax call when open a new windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user click a button, I generate a pdf who open in a new tab.

```
$("#memberContractPrintReport").on('click', function (e) {
    var url = prepareParamUrl($('#contractReportTableResult'));    
    window.open(getHostName() + "/report/document/contracts" + url, 'MemberContractReport');
});
```

Server changed its security policy. All url need authorization.

In a ajax call I add

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + $.cookie('user-authorization')
}
```

Comment: Well you are not going to be adding that to a new window. Why is the server not using cookies with that request?

Comment: without security that work.. i need a way to call url and content be displayed in another tab, window.

Comment: That is what sessions should do automatically. It should be sending up the cookie with the request and the server should be handling it.

Comment: there are no session....

Answer (score 0):

As per you if Ytord there are several types of securities for stateless communication that can be token, Basic etc. please share your authentication technique.. likewise you have edit the request.

Comment: header said it... Authorization": "Basic "